# Unit test: How best to provide an XML input?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc, xml

I need to write a unit test which validates the serialization of two attributes of an XML(size ~ 30 KB) file.

What is the best way to provide an input for this test?

Here are the options I have considered:

1. Add the file to the project and use a file reader
2. Pass the contents of the XML as a string
3. Create the XML through a program and pass it

Which is my best option and why? If there is another way which you think is better, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 is probably awkward since you will have to escape all double quotes `"` of the XML attributes.

Option 3 just moves the problem to another place.

Go for option 1. With an external XML file, you can use all the advantages of a XML editor to prepare the input.

Comment: Option 2 is bad because, ignoring all else, you're going to embed a 30KB string in your code. Option 3 doesn't scale for the next time the OP wants to have large XML input.